# React pass method as prop got undefined of another method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import ImageGallery from 'react-image-gallery'

    methodOne(){
       return (<div><ImageGallery /></div>)
    }

    methodTwo(){
       return (<h1>{this.methodOne()}</h1>)
    }

    render() {
       return(
         <AnotherCommonComponent methodTwo={this.methodTwo} />
       )
    }
```

I got methodOne of undefined when I trying to pass methodTwo as prop to another component. The strange thing is I can get methodOne working when I render directly like

```
render() {
       return(
         <methodTow />
       )
    }
```

Is it because of the `this` issue? I even tried

```
 methodOne = () => {
       return (<h1>h1 here</h1>)
    }
```

Nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error, change it to below mentioned code.

```js
render() {
       return(
         {this.props.methodTwo()}
       )
    }
```

Comment: Now you can check.

Comment: what are you trying to proof? methodOne is same level with methodTwo.

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind the this operator to the functions.
You could do that in the constructor

```js
....

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  
  this.methodOne = this.methodOne.bind(this);
  this.methodTwo = this.methodTwo.bind(this);
}

methodOne(){
   return (<h1>h1 here</h1>)
}

methodTwo(){
   return (<h1>{this.methodOne()}</h1>)
}

render() {
   return(
     <AnotherCommonComponent methodTwo={this.methodTwo} />
   )
}
```

Comment: have you tested this code? I tried but it won't work, methodOne content did not appear, no error.

Comment: How do you call methodTwo?

Comment: figured it out, need to wrap with `div`

Comment: In JavaScript, `this` within a function always equals the `global` object. That is, when not used in conjunction with `.call()`, `.bind()` or `.apply()`. You can also use arrow functions which will automatically change the context of `this`, it uses _lexical scoping_ which means `this` refers to the enclosing environment - in this case your React Component.

Answer (score 0):

```
methodOne(){
  return (<h1>h1 here</h1>)
 }

  methodTwo(){
    return (<h1>{this.methodOne()}</h1>)
 }

render() {
  return(
    <AnotherCommonComponent methodTwo={this.methodTwo.bind(this)} />
  )
 }
```

You need to bind this to **this.methodTwo** to access method one in AnotherCommonComponent.
Hope This Helps